# Selecting class inside div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select a class inside div.

**my code:**

```
<div id="cool" style="width: 80%;height: 80%;margin: auto;">    
    <a href="#" class="redirect"> cool</a>
</div>
```

**Selector:**

```
$('#cool .redirect').attr('href', google.com);
```

it does not work. Please suggest.

I'm a beginner and just started to learn jquery!

Comment: Your element has an `ID` redirect, not a `class`.

Comment: You want `$('div#cool a#redirect')`.

Comment: Just `$('#redirect')` would do, as `IDs` should be unique across the page.

Comment: `.attr('href', 'www.google.com');` fix the `URL` and don't forget the quotes around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/1652ces1/) once I correct your attempt to use `google.com` (that is, the value of the field named `com` in the nonexistent variable `google`).  Put quotation marks around the string and it works fine.

Comment: I can't upvote since it requires 15 reputation. I don't know why people gave my question downvote. Considering that it's a very basic question :(